# How does Time Stop interact with "End of Turn" durations?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, combat, time

The spell Time Stop allows you take take extra rounds of action during your turn. For the purpose of effects that have the duration of "End of Turn", would buffing yourself with something that lasted till the End of Turn be gone in 1 round of Time Stop? Cite sources if possible, please.

Comment: It would be useful to know what effect in particular caused this question.

Comment: Upon reading this question again, I can't discern if the creature who *cast* the spell *time stop* is using an effect that ends at the conclusion of the caster's turn **or** if a creature *outside* of the *time stop* has used an effect with a duration that ends at the conclusion of the not-caster's turn, the *time stop* then *interrupting* the not-caster's turn. (The latter case occurring if, for example, the caster readied an action to cast *time stop.* There are certainly [worse spells](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Summon_Potato_%283.5e_Spell%29) to ready.).

Answer (score 4):

#### Yes, even during the spell [*time stop*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/time-stop) an effect that ends at the conclusion of the casting creature's turn *still* ends at the conclusion the casting creature's turn

The 9th-level Sor/Wiz spell [*time stop*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/time-stop) says

> In fact, you speed up so greatly that all other creatures seem frozen, though they are actually still moving at their normal speeds. You are free to act for 1d4+1 rounds of apparent time.

In defining a [round](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary#TOC-Round) the game says that

> During an individual round, all creatures have a chance to take a turn to act, in order of initiative. A round represents 6 seconds in the game world.

In defining a [turn](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary#TOC-Turn) the game says that

> In a round, a creature receives one turn, during which it can perform a wide variety of actions. Generally in the course of one turn, a character can perform one standard action, one move action, one swift action, and a number of free actions. Less-common combination's of actions are permissible as well...

Thus the spell *time stop* grants extra rounds during which the creature that cast the spell *time stop* can take extra turns, and during those extra turns the creature can activate effects that last until the end of the creature's turn, and those effects will end when the creature's turn ends. The round continues, however, until the character can next take a turn, at which point it's the *next* round.

> **Example 1**
> A creature with the feat [Lunge](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/lunge-combat---final) casts the spell *time stop*. On its next turn, the creature uses the feat Lunge to get the feat's benefits. Those benefits last until the end of the creature's turn and the benefit *doesn't* continue beyond that. On the creature's next turn (during the next round of the spell *time stop*'s duration), it can employ the feat Lunge again to gain the feat's benefit during its turn.
>
> **Example 2**
> A creature casts the spell [*mythic blink*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/blink) followed by the spell *time stop*. The creature takes a move action to remain for its turn corporeal. When the creature's turn ends, it will no longer be corporeal, but on its *next* turn (during the next round of the spell *time stop*'s duration) it can take another move action to once again be corporeal until the end of its turn.

The spell *time stop* doesn't change *how* time works but instead gives the caster *more* of it.